# Rails Plugin for Multiple Ratings Per Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I'm looking to add the capability of rating a model I have under several different categories like "Knowledgeable" "Organized", etc.  Is there a plugin that will allow me to do this, and maybe even have a cool x/5 stars graphical representation as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any of the ratings plugins support this, but you could make a model called `CatgoricalRating` that is setup like this:

```
#This table has model_id, rating_category, and columns to support the rating system
class CatgoricalRating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
  acts_as_rateable  # (or any other rating plugin)
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorical_ratings
end
```

Then any model can have any number of ratings through that relationship

You could even make it a `has_many :through` where one model represents the categories, and the 'join' model associates one model with one category and also contains the rating information.

Comment: Great idea, I'll try to implement it!  Thanks! :)